# dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in`method_missing': undefined method `devise' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

fairly new to rails and was trying to put devise in my project and I keep getting this error whenever I try to start my server. Here is my routes.rb file.

[routes file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN82q.png)

I was expecting that I installed devise correctly and that my server would turn on but instead I keep getting this error. I've looked at every place I can find and tried what feels like everything but nothing is working.

Comment: Add the uncommented lines from your `config/initializers/devise.rb` file.